# Передача своих данных в HTTP-заголовках в ответ на Ajax-запрос — как?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, header, xhr

С сервера помимо основного контента в ответе на Ajax-запрос я могу же передавать еще и свои дополнительные HTTP-заголовки, для их дальнейшего использования в JavaScript'е?

К примеру: есть у меня HTML-страничка, в JavaScript-коде производится Ajax-запрос к PHP-скрипту. PHP-скрипт через функцию header() выдает какой-нибудь дополнительный HTTP-заголовок, а я в JavaScript'е использую его.

Есть ли пример такого взаимодействия?

Какие HTTP-заголовки я могу использовать для своих целей - т.е. для передачи из PHP нужных мне данных в JavaScript помимо основного ответа на запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для своих целей любые заголовки, включая нестандартные. Но нестандартные лучше на всякий случай начинать с префикса `X-` или даже `X-НазваниеВашегоПроекта-`

В этом вам помогут методы [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) и [`getResponseHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader)